# Using loops to eliminate numbers retrieved by array

Tags: php, arrays, loops

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<select>
<?php 
include 'connection.php';
$q = "SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE duration='first lecture' and day='Sunday'";
$r = mysql_query($q); 
$ro = mysql_num_rows($r);
if($ro==0) {
for($i=1; $i<=14; $i++) { ?>
<option value=""><?php echo $i; ?></option>
<?php
} }
else {
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($r)){

for ($i=1; $i<=14; $i++)
{
$exclude = array($row['name']);
if(in_array($i, $exclude)) continue;
?>
<option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
<?php
}
}
}
?>          
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to use a FOR LOOP to eliminate elements retrieved by an array in one loop. Suppose $row retrieved values (4,5), what I want with that FOR LOOP is to display numbers between 1 to 14 except (4,5).

I tried it many times and I succeed in that, but the loop in first time eliminate just (4) and in second time eliminate just (5).

Is there's a way to eliminate both at one time ?

I need $row['name'] because it check for availability of empty rooms range from 1 to 14 so if i select (4,5) it will be static method i need it dynamically

Comment: Why not exclude them in the query?

Comment: not recommended because you don't know which room i already reserved i guest give an example

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use your code and I think it is correct.

```
$exclude = array(4,5);
for ($i=1; $i<=14; $i++) {
   if (in_array($i, $exclude)) continue;
   echo $i.'<br/>';
}
```

By the way, can you show the result of the query? The problem might be in there perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

You can just compare two arrays.

```
$array1 = range(1,14); // Your 14 rooms
$array2 = array(4, 5); // The rooms taken
$result = array_diff($array1, $array2); // Find the rooms not taken

echo "<select>";
foreach($result as $rooms) {
    echo "<option value=''>" . $rooms . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: How did it not work? Remember that array_diff needs to have the arrays in the correct order. In this case, array_diff($array2, $array1) would not work.